# Maximizing a function's asymptotic growth

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, asymptotics

Let $F[\mathbb{N},[0,1]]$ be the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $[0,1]$.
Let $\alpha : \mathbb{N} \to [0,1]$ be any function in $F[\mathbb{N},[0,1]]$ and let $T : F[\mathbb{N},[0,1]] \to F[\mathbb{N},[0,1]] : \alpha \mapsto T[\alpha]$ be a higher-order function that maps the function $\alpha$ to the function $T[\alpha] : \mathbb{N} \to [0,1] : n \mapsto \alpha(n) / 2^{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \alpha(j)}$.

Let $\leq_\mathcal{O}$ be a total order on $F[\mathbb{N},[0,1]]$ induced by the big $\mathcal{O}$ notation, i.e., $f \leq_\mathcal{O} g \iff f \in \mathcal{O}(g)$.
Let $A_\mathcal{O} := \{\hat{\alpha} | \forall \alpha \in F[\mathbb{N},[0,1]] : T[\hat{\alpha}] \geq_\mathcal{O} T[\alpha]\}$ be the set of maximal functions w.r.t. $\geq_\mathcal{O}$.

1. Is it possible to find any element $\hat{\alpha} \in A_\mathcal{O}$? (In case $A_\mathcal{O} \neq \emptyset$.)
2. If finding $\hat{\alpha}$ is infeasible, can we at least find the asymptotic behavior of $T[\hat{\alpha}]$?
   Concretely, how can one prove (disprove) that for any $\alpha \in F[\mathbb{N},[0,1]]$ it holds that $T[\alpha](n) \in \mathrm{o}(1/n)$?

My observation so far:
If one restricts to "intuitive" functions $\alpha$, then the answer seems to lie between $\alpha(j) \sim 1/(j \ln(j))$ which yields $T[\alpha](n) \sim 1/(n\ln(n)^2)$ and $\alpha(i) \sim 1/(j\ln(j)^{1+\epsilon})$ which yields $T[\alpha](n) \sim 1/(n\ln(n)^{1+\epsilon})$.
These follow from bounding the sum $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \alpha(j)$ by $\int_1^n \alpha(j) \mathrm{d}j$ (neglecting constant factors).
However, this strategy fails when $\alpha$ is not integrable.

Comment: $T$ is actually surjective, since we can recursively construct $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(n) = f(n)\cdot 2^{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \alpha(j)}$ for any function $f\in F[\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R}]$, so there's no way to control $T$ over all $F[\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R}]$. In fact I believe it's even bijective.

Comment: Yes, you are right, for $\alpha \in F[\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R}]$ any $T[\alpha]$ is an image.
I edited the question to include a constraint I forgot $\alpha \in F[\mathbb{N},[0,1]]$.

Comment: Ok! Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} T[\alpha](n) = 0$, but I believe there is still no way to control the convergence rate. For any $f:\mathbb{N}\to[0,1]$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0$, we can define an $\alpha$ which is mostly equal to $0$, but jumps to $1$ whenever $1/2^{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \alpha(k)}$ would exceed $f(n)$, and so $T[\alpha] \not\in o(f)$.

Comment: True! This approach seems to break when considering the infinitely often order $f \leq_\mathrm{io} g \iff \forall n_0 \exists n \geq n_0 : f(n) \leq g(n)$.